# ExtendedXmlSerializer and the structure of xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

In my application I use the [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) installed with nuget.I am having difficulty working with the ExtendedXmlSerializer. My program has a settings file (.xml) and I want to store program settings in it in a compact and readable form. Users should be able to change the settings in the file. The ExtendedXmlSerializer does an excellent job of this, but the Xml markup is not readable.

The code looks like this:

```
    public class ConfigObject
    {
        public string Name = "Section name";
        public Dictionary<KeyConfig, Config> Items = new Dictionary<KeyConfig, Config>
        {
            { KeyConfig.Key1, new Config("Key1", "Value", "Description") },
            { KeyConfig.Key2, new Config("Key2", "Value", "Description") }
        };
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Value { get; }
        public string Description { get; }
        public Config(string name, string value, string description = "")
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            Description = description;
        }
    }
```

KeyConfig is an enumeration of settings in the application. The string representation of the enumeration element is equivalent to the value of the Name property of Config object.
KeyConfig is used only for convenient access to the settings dictionary. For example like this: Items[KeyConfig.Key1].Value
And serialization method:

```
        private static void writeConfig(ConfigObject obj, string name)
        {
            IExtendedXmlSerializer serializer = new ConfigurationContainer()
                .Type<ConfigObject>().Member(x => x.Name).Ignore()
                .EnableImplicitTyping(typeof(ConfigObject))
                .UseOptimizedNamespaces()
                .EnableParameterizedContent()
                .UseAutoFormatting()
                .Create();

            XmlWriterSettings options = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                Indent = true
            };

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(ConfigFilePath);
            XElement xSection = xDoc.Root.Element(name);
            if (xSection != null)
                xDoc.Root.Element(xSection.Name).Remove();
            if(obj != null)
                xDoc.Root.Add(xElementFromObject(obj, serializer, options));
            xDoc.Save(ConfigFilePath);
        }
```

As a result, I get the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <ConfigObject xmlns:sys="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/system" xmlns:exs="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/v2" xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp">
    <Items>
      <sys:Item Key="Key1">
        <Value Name="Key1" Value="Value" Description="Description" />
      </sys:Item>
      <sys:Item Key="Key2">
        <Value Name="Key2" Value="Value" Description="Description" />
      </sys:Item>
    </Items>
  </ConfigObject>
</Configuration>
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <ConfigObject xmlns:sys="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/system" xmlns:exs="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/v2">
    <Items>
      <Item Name="Key1" Value="Value" Description="Description" />
      <Item Name="Key2" Value="Value" Description="Description" />
    </Items>
  </ConfigObject>
</Configuration>
```

1. Is it possible to remove the namespace declaration 'xmlns:ns1="..."'
2. Is it possible to remove the prefix 'sys:...' when serializing dictionary elements
3. Is it possible when serializing KeyValuePair<Key, Value> to hide Key and to display Value as an xml attributes (meaning the class fields). Key in my case is an enumeration, Value is my class Config

Comment: By ExtendedXmlSerializer are you referring to https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/?

Comment: Your desired XML doesn't contain the dictionary keys anywhere, as far as I can see. I.e. `"Key1"` and `"Key2"` are not present in any form -- as element names, element values, or attribute values.  Is this really what you want -- to strip out the dictionary keys, and serialize only the values?  If so, how to you intend to deserialize?

Comment: Edited the question. Yes, I don't need to serialize the Key (if possible). The Key value is always the same as the Name attribute. During desiarilization, the Key must be restored from the value of the Name.

Comment: The question is still open.